# Object[] cannot be cast to resultado[]

Tags: java, android

I have this resultado class, where I implement what DataBaseManager did in one ArrayList Method:

package moviles.fingertwist;

```
public class resultado {

    private String id;
    private String resultado;

    public resultado(String Id, String Resultado)
    {
        id=Id;
        resultado = Resultado;
    }

    public String getResultad()
    {
        return resultado;
    }

}
```

and have this class DataBaseManager.java where I have the method that has interaction with the DB, :

```
public ArrayList ListaChida() { 

final ArrayList dirArray = new ArrayList(); Cursor d = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

d.moveToFirst();
while (!d.isAfterLast() ) {
resultado e = new resultado(d.getString(0),d.getString(1)); dirArray.add(e); d.moveToNext(); } d.close();

return dirArray;
}
```

so later in lista, where I want to make a ListView of the array I cant make it because of an error... :C heres the code:

```
public class lista extends Activity { ListView listView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);



    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //recibe datos de resultado

    DataBaseManager dbm = new DataBaseManager(this);
    resultado[] dirArray=   (resultado[]) dbm.ListaChida().toArray();
    String[] Res = new String[dbm.ListaChida().size()];
    for(int i = 0; i< dbm.ListaChida().size(); i++)
    {
        resultado res=dirArray[i];
        Res[i] = res.getResultad();
    }



    // Define a new Adapter
    // First parameter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
    // Forth - the Array of data

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, Res);


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

}
}
```

I got the error: object[] cannot be cast to resultado[] ?? Can anyone wxplain me how to fix it and why it throws taht error?

Comment: Please do not post questions multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `toArray` you called returns an array of `Object`s. You can't cast from an array of `Object`s to an array of non-`Object`s. Instead, use the other version of `toArray`:

```
resultado[] dirArray= dbm.ListaChida().toArray(new resultado[0]);
```

There are good reasons to ban this cast. Imagine what would happen if you can cast it:

```
Object [] a = new Object[2];
a[0] = "blue";
a[1] = "red";
String [] b = (String []) a; // a and b now refer to the same array; this does NOT work!!
a[0] = new Date(); 
// What's b[0] now?
```